# Is the cyclic group $\langle x\rangle$ always a subgroup of $G$ for any $x\in G$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

I have been thinking about the following:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $x\in G$ an element of order $n$ is then $\langle x\rangle$ always a subgroup of $G$?

I have the definition that $\langle x\rangle=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{{\rm ord}(x)-1}\}$

Do check this I know that I should check the following three points:

1. $1_G\in \langle x\rangle$. This is clear since $x^0=1$.
2. Stable under inverses: Let $u\in \langle x\rangle$. Then $u=x^i$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$. I claim that $u^{-1}=(x^{n-1})^i$ is the inverse of $u$. Indeed $$x^i(x^{n-1})^i=x^i(x^{ni-i})=x^{ni}=(x^n)^i=1_G^i=1_G$$ And since $\langle x\rangle$ is abelian $u^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse of $u$. Furthermore  it is clear that $u^{-1}\in \langle x\rangle$.
3. Stable under composition: let $u,v\in \langle x\rangle$, then $u=x^i, v=x^j$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Then $uv=x^ix^j=x^{i+j}\in \langle x\rangle$

According to this proof I think my claim should be correct but I'm not 100% sure, thats why I wanted to ask if someone could take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't $\langle x\rangle$ by definition the smallest subgroup of $G$ that includes $x$?  If it isn't, what definition are you using?

Comment: What is your definition of $\langle x\rangle$? Sometimes, this is defined as "the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $x$", in which case this is obvious. On the other hand, it can be defined to be the set $\{x^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, in which case there is something to be proven. You need to specify which definition you have.

Comment: So this could be, would also make sence but we only have the definition that $\langle x\rangle=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{ord(x)}\}$. Would then my prove work

Comment: @aprozz: Each $x^j$ is in $G$, so $\langle x\rangle\subseteq G$.

Comment: @markvs, ah but this doesn't show that $\langle x\rangle$ is a subgroup with my definition

Comment: @MJD I added to the statement that G is finite. Does it now work with my definition?

Comment: @aprozz: To prove that it is a subgroup, you only need to prove that it is closed under multiplication: $x^ix^j\in \langle x\rangle$

Comment: @markvs hmm okey so we always checked all three points, nevertheless would it work with all three points or are there still some mistakes?

Comment: @aprozz: Point 3 which is the only point needed to be proved, is not proved.

Comment: @markvs now I'm a bit confused since in the answer below they write that it works. Why is it not proved because if $i+j< n$ then $x^{i+j}\in \langle x\rangle$ and if $i+j\geq n$ then $x^{i+j}=1_G\in \langle x\rangle$. Doesn't this prove point 3

Comment: If $i+j>n$ then $x^{i+j}\ne 1_G$.

Comment: oh I see but then what would you do in this case? can we still show this point?

Comment: That is a *bad* definition. What do you do when $x$ is not a torsion element? You should have one definition of $\langle x\rangle$ ( and more generally, for $\langle S\rangle$ where $S$ is a subset of $G$) that is the same for any group, not one definition in the finite case and a different one if $x$ is not of finite order.

Comment: The proposition is valid for any group (even infinite) and for all elements of the group not only those with finite order .

Comment: @OussamaAkar as you maybe can read I have still a problem in my prove since I don't see why $x^{i+j}\in \langle x\rangle$. I know your prove but I also want to complete mine. So do you have a hint how to complete this part

Comment: Hint : note that if $i+j>n$ think about the reminder of the division of $ i+j $ by $n$

Comment: @OussamaAkar so you mean with the euclidean algorithm? because we have never discussed it theoretically

Comment: Just plain division. Write $i+j = n + k$ with $0\leq k\lt n$ (possible, since $0\leq i,j\lt n$, so $i+j\lt 2n$), and then note that $x^{i+j} = x^{n+k} = x^nx^k$....

Comment: ah okey and then $x^{i+j}=x^k\in \langle x\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is correct . Hence it is not necessary that $x$ is an element of finite order neither should $G$ be finite .

I propose the following proof .

let $x$ be an element of  $G$ (with no condition on $x$)

Consider the application, $f: \mathbb{Z} \to G$
, such that for all k in $\mathbb{Z}$ , $f(k)=x^k$

You can proof that $f$ is a morphism of groups .

Note that :  any two integers $k,l$ ;  $f(k+l)=f(k)∗f(l)$

Then $f(\mathbb{Z})=\{x^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of G. i.e $  \langle x\rangle$  is a subgroup of G.

Comment: ou smart way, so then we neither need that $G$ is finite.

Comment: no there is no condition on G actually .

Comment: Thank you very much this is a really smart way

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this approach, as proving that this map is a morphism requires much the same working as we'd use to prove the set is a subgroup. (As in, currently the answer hides the working behind a good idea, but the idea isn't as magical as it first appears as that working still needs to be done.)

Comment: Actually it does not require that much of a proof . note simply that for any two integers $k,l$ ;   $f(k+l)=f(k)*f(l)$

Comment: And this is much shorter than showing that it is a subgroup directly .

Comment: @Oussama No. The issue is that you are ignoring the definition given in the question. (See my comments below the other answer for more details.)

Comment: I understand what you mean now , My claim is that $
G$  doesn't need to be finite and  $ x$ does not need to be of finite order , the case in question is merely a particular case of what has been proven generally .

Comment: @Oussama I don't think you do understand my point. This *does not work* if $x$ has infinite order, as (by the definition in the question) $\langle x\rangle$ contains only *positive* powers, so will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ (a monoid). In your proof, you need to justify that $f(k)*f(l)\in\langle x\rangle$, and this requires some modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry but I have to agree with @user1729 that your proof is wrong because it does not use the given definition for $⟨x⟩$. Sure, we know it's the same as what you wrote, but at the asker's level it pays to be absolutely clear about what is going on, since as you can see the asker is **not** actually clear about that. Ping me after you have fixed your answer and I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

In fact, neither the order of the element $x$ nor of the group $G$ need be finite. I will concentrate on the case when ${\rm ord}\, x$ is finite.

Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since $e=x^0\in\langle x\rangle$, we have $\langle x\rangle\neq \varnothing$.

Let $y\in\langle x\rangle$. Then $y=x^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. But all powers of $x$ are in $G$ by closure of $G$. Hence $y\in G$. Hence $\langle x\rangle\subseteq G$.

Let $a=x^r, b=x^s\in \langle x\rangle$. Then

$$\begin{align}
ab^{-1}&=x^r(x^s)^{-1}\\
&=x^rx^{-s}\\
&=x^{r-s},
\end{align}$$

which is in $\langle x\rangle$ by taking the power modulo ${\rm ord}\, x$: we can do this by Euclid's algorithm, by finding $0\le m<{\rm ord}\, x$ and $q\in\Bbb Z$ such that $r-s=q{\rm ord}\, x+m$, since then

$$\begin{align}
x^{r-s}&=x^{q{\rm ord}\, x+m}\\
&=(x^{{\rm ord }\, x})^qx^m\\
&=e^qx^m\\
&=x^m.
\end{align}$$

Hence $ab^{-1}\in\langle x\rangle$.

Hence $\langle x\rangle\le G$.

Comment: ah okey also a nice way, so I didn't know this one step subgroup test but this seems to be usful.

Comment: Hmm, I'm also not convinced by this answer. The issue is that (by the definition in the question) the element *must* have finite order to be a subgroup, as $\langle x\rangle$ contains only positive powers so in the infinite case we get $\mathbb{N}$ (a monoid). This issue has seeped into your working: it is not immediate that $x^{r-s}\in\langle x\rangle$, as there is no reason why $0\leq r-s\leq ord(x)$ - we have to use modular arithmetic here. (Same issue is in the solution you wrote in the question @aprozz - you need to use modular arithmetic to conclude that $x^{i+j}\in\langle x\rangle$.)

Comment: @user1729 where did I write this with $x^{r-s}$

Comment: (@aprozz You wrote $x^{i+j}$ rather than $x^{r-s}$, but it is the same underlying error. However, I've just spotted in the comments to the question that you noticed this in your discussion with markvs - this really is the crux of the question, and both answers ignore it!)

Comment: Sorry I don't see where do you mean. So but the two answers did another way so they don't need to check this because their approach is different!

Comment: It's not the best of fixes, @user1729, but I've added that the powers need to be taken modulo ${\rm ord}\, x$.

Comment: @user1729 yes but at the end of the long comment list we shown how to work with such exponents so we could do the same for $x^{r-s}$ or am I wrong?

Comment: @aprozz All 3 solutions have issues at this point. In your solution you do not prove that $x^{i+j}\in\langle x\rangle$ (as $i+j$ can be larger than $ord(x)$), the answer here does not prove that $x^{r-s}\in\langle x\rangle$ (as $r-s$ can be negative), while the other answer hides this step when they say that "you can prove it is a morphism".

Comment: So but under the question in the comments we wrote that since $i+j>n$ we can write $i+j=n+k$ for some $0\leq k <n$. This works since $0\leq i,j<n$ and therefore  $i+j<2n$. And then $x^{i+j}=x^nx^k=1x^k=x^k$ but $x^k\in \langle x\rangle$

Comment: @Shaun I think it is instructive to be pedantic here, and so I will say that your fix isn't good enough! :-) [You need to replace $r-s$ with a number between $0$ and $ord(x)$ such that they are equal modulo this order, and actually *replace* rather than being fuzzy like you've currently written.]

Comment: @aprozz I was just referring to what you'd written in the question, not to the comments below it. (As I said above, you spotted this error in a comment there.)

Comment: yes but we could solve it so I think at least one way works without "hiding" something now

Comment: @aprozz I suggest you write up a (corrected) solution as an answer, using the comments to the question as a guide. Currently, neither answer "works" for the reasons I explain above.

Comment: I agree. Is that any better, @user1729? (Thank you for pointing this out. I'm so excited about nearly getting the golden group theory tag badge, my standards are starting to slip.)

Comment: @Shaun yes, that looks better now :-)

Comment: You shouldn't use `{\rm ord}` in your LaTeX formula because it yields the wrong spacing. Instead put `$\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}$` at the start of your post and then you can use `\ord` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

We have disscussed several solutions, and as suggested from @user1729 I put in a correct solution with the comments. I use the way I started in the question. So we check the following three points:

1. $1_G\in \langle x\rangle$. This is clear since $x^0=1$.
2. Stable under inverses: Let $u\in \langle x\rangle$. Then $u=x^i$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$. I claim that $u^{-1}=(x^{n-1})^i$ is the inverse of $u$. Indeed $$x^i(x^{n-1})^i=x^i(x^{ni-i})=x^{ni}=(x^n)^i=1_G^i=1_G$$ And since $\langle x\rangle$ is abelian $u^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse of $u$. Furthermore  it is clear that $u^{-1}\in \langle x\rangle$.
3. Stable under composition: let $u,v\in \langle x\rangle$, then $u=x^i, v=x^j$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Then $uv=x^ix^j=x^{i+j}$. Here it is not clear that $x^{i+j} \in \langle x\rangle$. But remark that since $0\leq i,j<n$ implies that $i+j<2n$ thus we can find $0\leq k<n$ such that $i+j=n+k$ and therefore $$x^{i+j}=x^{n+k}=x^nx^k=x^k\in \langle x \rangle$$

I hope this works now

Comment: Is it clear that $ni-i\leq ord(x)$? (Otherwise, good job!)

Comment: sorry it's a bit late... you mean why $u^-1\in \langle x \rangle$

Comment: Yes, you have the same issue there. You just need $x^{-i}$, but then use the same trick as in part (3) to get a representative in the required range.

Comment: @user1729: Of course it is not clear; it is false, so this proof is wrong. aprozz: If you want to do it this way, you should prove closure under product first, so that *after that* you can trivially assert that $(x^{n-1})^i ∈ ⟨x⟩$. Also, your proof of closure under product is slightly incorrect. You correctly observe that $i+j < 2n$, but then wrongly claim that $i+j = n+k$ for some $0 ≤ k < n$. Of course you don't mean that, so be careful to say the right thing: **Either** $i+j < n$ **or** $n ≤ i+j < 2n$, and in the latter case $0 ≤ i+j-n < n$ so $x^{i+j} = x^{i+j-n} ∈ ⟨x⟩$.